# Assign values to multiple variables

Tags: python

In python we can

```
a,b = tuple_with_two_items
a,b,c = tuple_with_three_items
```

Can we have something like

```
a,b,c = tuple_with_two_or_three_items
```

, so that when there are 3 items in the tuple, all `a,b,c` have values, while when there are only 2 items, `c` will take `None`?

Note: grammarly I know this does not work, I'm looking for some one-liner quick work-around.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: No, it will raise an exception saying that there aren't enough values to unpack.

Comment: Have you considered writing an if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you `None` for `c`:

```
a, b, c, *_ = *tuple_with_two_or_three_items, None
```

Or with Python 3.10:

```
match tuple_with_two_or_three_items:
    case a, b, c:
        pass
    case a, b:
        c = None
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, a general solution could be somethig like `a,b,c,d,e,*_ = *t2, *[None for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: @athos Or just `a,b,c,d,e,*_ = *t2, *[None]*5`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest would be:

```
a, b, *c = tuple_with_two_or_three_items
```

`c` will be a list of all the items after the first 2. If there are only 2 items, `c` will be empty, otherwise it will be contain the third value (and more if there are more than 3).

Comment: Just for OP’s clarity: … and third, fourth, fifth, etc. if the tuple should contain that many elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to pad the size of a tuple:

```
def pad_tuple(items, n, fill=None):
    if len(items) < n:
        return items + (fill,)*(n-len(items))
    return items
```

Then use it like this:

```
a, b, c = pad_tuple(tuple_with_two_or_three_items, 3)
```

(but an if-statement would probably be easier)

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an `itertools` function that does this.

Comment: @Barmar [more_itertools.padded](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.padded) seems to do this and more.